# Problema al agrupar datos en consulta

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql

Tengo 3 tablas:

- "Clientes" con id, cod_cliente,id_c (código CRM del cliente), nombre y cif.
- "Máquinas", con los campos id, id_maq (código CRM), fecha_instalacion, duración, id_tarifa, num_serie, cod_cliente, id_cliente (código crm), id_coste y caducidad.
- "Contador" se basa en las siguientes columnas (carga a través de CSV):
  id, modelo, num_serie, fecha_contador, page_color, page_bn, facturado.

Esta tabla se relaciona con las otras 2 tanto para mostrar los datos de los contadores de las máquinas individualmente como por grupo de empresas (todas las máquinas que tiene una empresa) para posteriormente rellenar la factura en el crm sin tener que teclear línea a línea.

Lo normal en la tabla "Contador" es que se vuelque 2 veces al mes como mínimo a través de CSV los datos de dichas máquinas y como ejemplo la primera vez que se vuelcan los datos sucede lo siguiente:

```
num_serie:A,B,D
fecha_contador:25/12/2017,24/12/2017,15/12/2017
page_color:25.000,23.000,4.000
page_bn:100.000,150.000,3.000
facturado:1,1,1
```

La segunda vez que se vuelcan los datos tenemos:

```
num_serie:A,B,C,D
fecha_contador:12/01/2018,12/01/2018,08/01/2018,10/01/2018
page_color:26.000,27.000,5.000,5.500
page_bn:110.000,155.000,3.200,3.500
facturado:0,0,1,0
```

Los valores de la columna "facturado" me permiten conocer los datos anteriores(1) y actuales(0) para realizar los cálculos para la facturación.

Por lo que el **color anterior** mostraría para cada máquina **(25.000,23.000,4.000,5000)** y el **color actual** debería mostrar **(26.000,27.000, sin datos, 5.500)** y lo que muestra es **(26.000,27.000,5.500,---)**

Viendo los datos, cuando realizó la consulta agrupada por máquinas, A,B,C y D me mostrará los datos anteriores que son los de Diciembre del 2017 para A,B y D y del 2018 para C (1,1,1,1) pero en los actuales de Enero del 2018 las máquinas A y B me mostrarán los datos correctos actuales pero C y D no. C debería mostrarme la etiqueta "Sin datos" y D su valor correspondiente, pero lo que ocurre es que C coge el valor de D y D me muestra sus datos en blanco. Me muestra los valores (0,0,0) y debería ser (0,0,sin datos,0).

Como se puede apreciar se inicia con 3 máquinas y sus correspondientes valores, posteriormente se vuelcan datos donde aparece una nueva máquina. Al final añado una nueva imagen, donde se pueden observar los campos a rellenar (lo datos dentro del círculo rojo son erróneos ya que deberían decir "sin datos").

Os muestro el código:

```
<td>
<?php
//Actual Color
$sql="SELECT * FROM(SELECT distinct m.num_serie,cl.cod_cliente,nombre,MAX(page_color) as pc,facturado,fecha_contador FROM contador as co,maquinas as m INNER JOIN cliente as cl ON (m.cod_cliente = cl.cod_cliente) where cl.cod_cliente='".$_GET['empresa']."' and co.num_serie=m.num_serie and facturado=0 group by num_serie asc) cont group by num_serie asc";
$resultadosc = mysqli_query($conexio,$sql);

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadosc)){   
do {
?>
<input type="text" name="Q_color_actual[]" id="contacto1" style="border:none; width:80px; height:40px;" value="<?php echo $row['pc']; ?>"/>
<?php } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadosc));
} else { echo 'Sin Datos'; } ?>
</td>
```

He probado con `while if else` y sigue el mismo resultado, si veis en la imagen los datos en rojo corresponden al ´ltimo valor y no a ese, que es donde debería aparecer el texto "Sin datos", dado que la fila no existe para el valor 0.

[image: error consulta]

Alguna solución a este problema sería de agradecer. Espero ahora se entienda

Nueva imagen
[image: Error en resultados]

Comment: Está muy confusa su pregunta, si pudiera redactarla más especificamente podría ayudarle, mejor.

Comment: Veamos, subo un archivo CSV con datos de los contadores, la primera vez que se sube el num_serie de una máquina por defecto tiene en la columna "facturado" un valor 1 en la primera fila, cuando se vuelve a subir un nuevo archivo con el mismo num_serie de esa máquina en esa misma columna, en la fila 2, se añade un 0.

Comment: Error comentario anterior. el problema es que debe mostrarme **sin datos** cuando no existe una fila en la BBDD y no coger el valor de otra máquina, mostrarlo y dejar esa máquina sin valor, como se aprecia en la imagen columna **color y fecha actual** 2 últimos valores. Gracias

Comment: Samuel, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Viendo tu consulta de la impresión de que se puede mejorar y simplificar, pero poder ayudarte deberás ser más claro en tu pregunta y sobre el resultado que quieres obtener, poniendo ejemplos de resultados reales e indicando cómo están formadas las tablas que intervienen en la consulta.

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu bienvenida A. Cedano acabo de modificar la pregunta, espero ahora se entienda, gracias de nuevo.